# What to do if I have a "Do not know how to load 'dart:html' " when loading library?

Tags: import, libraries, dart

The first two lines in my dart library are:

```
#library('LibraryName');
#import('dart:html');
```

When I try to load the library from another .dart file with

```
#import('../path/to/LibraryName.dart');
```

I get the following error:

```
Do not know how to load 'dart:html''file:///the/path/to/LibraryName.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
#import('dart:html');
^
```

The `#import('dart:html')` works fine when I use the library as a standalone app, but I want to be able to access it as a library from another dart app.

How can I use the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dart:html specifically is only available in the browser side.  This looks like you are trying to run a client side script with dart.exe on the server side.

dart:html is available on the browser (and interacts with the DOM)
dart:io is available on the server (and interacts with the OS)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
#import("../path/to/fileContaingLibrary.dart");
```

Plus the library system is changing soon.

> Note: The library system in Dart will change. This section describes
>   how it currently works. [link](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/language-tour/#libraries-library)

Comment: Oops, that's what I've got in code, I just didn't type it into the question properly.  I've updated the question now.